# Pandas Net Transactions when 3 Lines Similar

Tags: pandas, duplicates, invoice

[image]

I'm trying to identify duplicate invoices. In my dataset, I have instances where there are correction that are causing me to identify false positives. I would like to figure out a way to net correction and only return the final invoice.

In my example the first 3 transactions are all related. I would like to write something using pandas that will identify that the first two lines net out and only leaves 3rd line.

Code to Create the table

```
df =   pd.DataFrame({'Reference Number': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 'InvoiceNumber': {0: 'A123', 1: 'A123', 2: 'A123', 3: 'A342', 4: 'A444'},
 'InvoiceAmount': {0: 100, 1: -100, 2: 100, 3: 123, 4: 345},
 'DocType': {0: 'IN', 1: 'AD', 2: 'IN', 3: 'IN', 4: 'IN'},
 'Date': {0: '1/1/2022',
  1: '1/2/2022',
  2: '1/3/2022',
  3: '1/3/2022',
  4: '1/3/2022'}})
```

What I would want the table to look like when finished:

[image]

Comment: Why the first 3 transactions are related? Just by the invoice number?

Comment: Yes, the invoice number indicates they are related.

Comment: So you can just keep the last occurrence of a same invoice number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation between different invoices are not clear.

It could be simply:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates('InvoiceNumber', keep='last')
   Reference Number InvoiceNumber  InvoiceAmount DocType      Date
2                 3          A123            100      IN  1/3/2022
3                 4          A342            123      IN  1/3/2022
4                 5          A444            345      IN  1/3/2022
```